# how can I sum amounts in columns that change every month

Tags: excel

I need to sum amounts in columns that change every month.

**Example** In April I need to add amount that come up in 2 months: `Mar 17 and Apr 17`, Next month in `May 17` I need to add amounts that come up in `Mar, April and May`.

Every month there is another column that is added and amounts need to add to previous once.

- 2017-03
- 2017-04
- 2017-05
- 2017-06

`-15, -7, -8, -9`

What formula do I use to sum all these amounts every month

Comment: Could you please post some screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

Without further information with screenshot, I would suggest this:

If the all the data to be summed up is in column B, try

```
=SUM(B:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Col 10         Col 11       Col 12 
March -2017  April 2017   Sum in April
10              20           =Sum(March 2017:April 2017)
Next month I have three months:

Col 9         Col 10       Col 11   Col 12
March 2017  April 2017  May 2017  Sum in May
10              20          25        =Sum(March 2017:May 2017)

What formula do I need to write to pick up columns starting March 2017 to Feb2018.
Keep in mind workbook has only 12 columns from Col 1 to col 12 and every time a new month is adding I need formula to pick up column moving toward left hand side.

Col 12 is fixed and relates to formula which Sum all columns.